# is there a PulseAudio module that mirrors audio from one channel to another?

Tags: pulseaudio

I need this to listen to YouTube videos that have audio only on one side, which I find annoying (apparently so do the people who upvote to the top the "my left/right ear enjoyed this video" comments).

I thought this can and should be doable with a module, since I already can use the `module-remap-sink` in this command to swap the channels:

```
 pactl load-module module-remap-sink \
    sink_name=reverse-stereo \
    master='source-sink-name' \
    channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-right,front-left \
    channel_map=front-left,front-right
```

(this command creates a new sink with swapped channels)

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for a new module for this purpose, you can use the same module if you slightly modify your command:

if you want to mirror the left side to the right:

```bsh
 pactl load-module module-remap-sink \
    sink_name=reverse-stereo \
    master='source-sink-name' \
    channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-right,front-left \
    channel_map=front-left,front-left
```

and if you want to mirror the right side to the left:

```bsh
 pactl load-module module-remap-sink \
    sink_name=reverse-stereo \
    master='source-sink-name' \
    channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-right,front-left \
    channel_map=front-right,front-right
```